# I didn't run "Yarn add react-native" to a folder, will I run into issues when starting a project? I'm a noob and am just starting out

Tags: macos, yarnpkg

I used the CLI to install React Native, Node and Python but was not aware if I needed to save it to a file first. 

I ran the yarn command:

**➜ ~yarn add `<package>`**

I would get this warning message when running yarn check:
**➜  ~ yarn check**

```
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
warning "jest-haste-map#fsevents#node-pre-gyp@^0.12.0" could be deduped from "0.12.0" to "node-pre-gyp@0.12.0"
```

**Questions:**

1. Do I only ~ yarn add  when I start a project?

2. Since I've installed python, node, and react-native without creating a project folder will I run into issues down the road?

3. Do I add the json file with the licenses manually when starting a project with yarn?

4. Am I hopeless? lol

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling from yarn and updating yarn. Also, I've tried installing python and node from Homebrew to see if that changes anything.

Below is a log of the output from the CLI after running `~ yarn check`

```
Last login: Sat Aug 24 02:21:38 on ttys001
➜  ~ yarn check   
yarn check v1.17.3
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
warning "jest-haste-map#fsevents#node-pre-gyp@^0.12.0" could be deduped from "0.12.0" to "node-pre-gyp@0.12.0"
success Folder in sync.
✨  Done in 1.99s.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** I figured it out! So after poking around I realized that once I started a project I had a yarn.lock and package.json file one level up in the directory where the file was located. What I did was I deleted `yarn.lock` and `package.json` associated with the folder in the directory. After that was complete I then went into my project and installed the correct packages.

Answer (score 0):

*You're* not hopeless. *This project* may be, you've bitten off waaaay more than you can chew yet.

To answer your main question:

`yarn add` and it's cousin `npm install` will install the thing you tell them to in the `node_modules` folder in the directory you run the command in. The reason it's yelling at you is because usually you'll want to *save* the thing you installed as a dependency of your project, and you can't do that without a `package.json` file. You should run `npm init` to set up the `package.json` file for your project, then running `yarn add` will actually save it to the dependencies list so that you have a reproducible. If you have a `package.json` file already, it sounds like you maybe created it by hand (since it's missing a license field?) rather than have npm set it up for you, which is a bad idea.

Two more things:

1. React Native is awesome! ...But, it's a tool for people who already have good familiarity with Javascript command line/tooling/ecosystem/coding/React to build mobile apps. It is a *lousy* choice for a first project if you're just getting started with programming. Building a webpage with React is a lot easier, but even that may be too much.
2. If you really want to build a React Native app and you just can't wait [look at this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/) to get started.

But seriously, learn Javascript then npm then yarn then React then React Native. In that order.

Comment: **Solution** I figured it out! So after poking around I realized that once I started a project I had a yarn.lock and package.json file one level up in the directory where the file was located. What I did was I deleted `yarn.lock` and `package.json` associated with the folder in the directory. After that was complete I then went into my project and installed the correct packages.